# Entidade relacionada em página Razor

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

Estou com um problema em uma página Razor, tenho uma entidade "Pessoa" que possui um relacionamento com a entidade "Endereco"

```
public class Pessoa
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Nome {get; set;}
public virtual Endereco EnderecoPessoa {get; set;}
}

public class Endereco
{
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Logradouro {get; set;}
public int PessoaId {get; set;}
public Pessoa Pessoa {get; set;}
}
```

Como configuro na página Razor para receber os dados do endereço?

Já tentei das seguintes formas:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco)
```

e também

```
<input asp-for="EnderecoPessoa.Logradouro" class="form-control" />
```

Em nenhum dos casos, recebo os dados do endereço no controller quando posto o formulario.

Como faço para receber os dados do endereço o controller ?

Comment: Como os dados de pessoa é passado pra View? Há uma controller provavelmente onde você faz alguma consulta e envia a model para a View, correto? Posta ela.

Comment: é um cadastro, não tem dado sendo enviado para a View, apenas da View para o controller. Todos os dados são recebidos, menos os dados do endereço.

Comment: Então coloque o código da view, por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Você deve utilizar o "caminho completo"

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco.Logradouro)
```